# Can't push or present view controller

Tags: swift

This is the function that gets called when a user presses the charge my card button. Charging the card works, but upon pushing the button, the user stays on the same screen. I tried both pushing and presenting but neither worked. Any ideas as to why/how to fix this?

```
@objc private func handleChargeCardButtonPressed() {
    guard let last4 = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "last4") as? String else { return }
    chargeCardOnFile(amount: amountToCharge, last4: last4)
    let scanQRVC: UIViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "cardRegisteredVC")
    navigationController?.pushViewController(scanQRVC, animated: true)
    //present(scanQRVC, animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this below code.

Instead of returning for empty userDefaults value, we are making fatalError.Also checks the navigationController present or not.

```
@objc private func handleChargeCardButtonPressed() {
    guard
        let last4 = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "last4") as? String
    else {
        // check whether the function returns from here or not?
        // use fataError()
        fatalError("last4 is not present in the user defaults")
    }
    chargeCardOnFile(amount: amountToCharge, last4: last4)
    let scanQRVC: UIViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main",
                                                  bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "cardRegisteredVC")

    // make sure the navigation controller is present.
    guard let navController = navigationController else {
        fatalError("No Navigation Controller present for this view")
    }
    navController.pushViewController(scanQRVC, animated: true)
}
```

Edit:

From the discussion understood the console is showing error:

> while an existing transition or presentation is occurring; the navigation stack will not be updated.

This means an existing navigation stack is in progress while new push/present is being tried. (i) Try refactoring the call to this present/push to next view controller so that the previous call finishes to click on the button or (ii) add a delay when pushing next view controller(`DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) { }`).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately when I try your approach the problem remains the same.

Comment: Add a print statement or add a breakpoint on the first line of the function and make sure the function is getting called. Also how is the function mapped with the button?

Comment: It's definitely getting called because an order was successful message pops up and the balance is updated on firebase and square dashboard shows the charge. I'm not sure what you mean by how the function is mapped with the button.

Comment: Can you call this UI action(push/present another view controller) from a main thread, to make sure it is not causing any exceptions? But ideally that should show console error saying same. Also you already tried this right `present(scanQRVC, animated: true, completion: nil)`?

Comment: Yes, I tried that. I tried Dispatch....main function and it didn't solve the problem. I saw this in the console though:      pushViewController:animated: called on <UINavigationController 0x7fb2bb044400> while an existing transition or presentation is occurring; the navigation stack will not be updated.

Comment: try `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) { }`, it means, you previous animation is not yet finished. So question seems to be confusing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188715/discussion-between-jay-and-michaeldebo).

Answer (score 0):

OK i have method for guide you if you same my problem case.

The reason issue is problem about stack navigation.

**You can try this on you navigation**.

```
_ = destinationController()
```

meaning line maybe is possible that calling the view property of the destination view controller is causing it to load its view, which may in turn be causing the view controller to be pushed onto the navigation stack. However, this behavior is not guaranteed and may depend on other factors such as the implementation of the view controller's viewDidLoad() method or the presence of segues in the storyboard.

**example my case**

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "nameStoryboard", bundle: nil)
            
let destinationVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NameStoryboardID") as! NameViewController
_ = destinationVC.view
        
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(destination, animated: true)
```

I hope this help another.